# Agrupamiento de nodos en Grafos python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, teoría-de-grafos

Buen día a todos,

He intentado realizar lo siguiente pero no doy con lo que necesito obtener.

Tengo el siguiente grafo.

```
import networkx as nx    
G_pc = nx.Graph()
nodos=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
G_pc.add_nodes_from(nodos)
borde=[(0,13),(0,14),(1,17),(2,18),(3,13),(4,17),(5,17),(5,13),(6,12),(6,15),(7,14),(8,11),(8,13)   ,(9,14),(10,16),(10,18),(11,16),(12,14)]
G_pc.add_edges_from(borde)
peso=[(0,13,20.5589012853715),(0,14,25.4177434046609),(1,17,36.2618645532395),(2,18,16.8703999582542),(3,13,34.3863683718127)   ,(4,17,30.0351171023635),(5,17,33.9822809344501),(5,13,18.0200934317999),(6,12,39.2422565435151),   (6,15,22.2532908062227),(7,14,19.4260879503034),(8,11,41.3183215038238),(8,13,34.278901568112),(9,14,33.7961759649886),(10,16,23.5517464403996),(10,18,28.1699993580065),(11,16,15.6238382977572),(12,14,36.8538761297749)]
G_pc.add_weighted_edges_from(peso)

nx.draw_networkx(G_pc)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento obtener es si estoy en el nodo 13, me extraiga todos los nodos que estén por debajo del nodo 13 asumiendo que el nodo 0 es el inicio:

13 : (3,5,17,1,4,8,11,16,10,18,2)

Si estoy en el nodo 5:

5: (17,1,4)

Si estoy en el nodo 8:

8: (11,16,10,18,2)

Así sucesivamente de todos los nodos.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero sería convertir tu grafo en un árbol, puesto que realmente estás hablando de una estructura de tipo árbol al considerar un nodo "raíz" (el 0) del cual van "descendiendo" ramas.

No estoy muy familiarizado con la biblioteca `networkx`, por lo que no sé si dispone de alguna función específica para árboles (he mirado la documentación y no la he encontrado). No obstante sí que tiene un método para convertir todo tu grafo a un diccionario de listas, sobre el cual después se puede trabajar para reducirlo a un árbol, usando recursión. Mira:

Si usamos el método `nx.to_dict_of_lists()` obtenemos la siguiente estructura de datos:

```
>>> nx.to_dict_of_lists(G_pc)
{0: [13, 14],
 1: [17],
 2: [18],
 3: [13],
 4: [17],
 5: [17, 13],
 6: [12, 15],
 7: [14],
 8: [11, 13],
 9: [14],
 10: [16, 18],
 11: [8, 16],
 12: [6, 14],
 13: [0, 3, 5, 8],
 14: [0, 7, 9, 12],
 15: [6],
 16: [10, 11],
 17: [1, 4, 5],
 18: [2, 10]}
```

Que nos dice, para cada nodo, cual es su lista de vecinos. Casi es lo que necesitabamos, pero no, puesto que por ejemplo entre la lista de vecinos del 13 aparece el 0, que no queremos considerar porque sería "padre" y sólo te interesan los "hijos".

```
from collections import defaultdict

def to_list_of_dicts_tree(G):
  visited = set()
  as_dict = nx.to_dict_of_lists(G)
  result = defaultdict(list)

  def recurse(v):
      visited.add(v)
      for node in sorted(as_dict[v]):
        if node not in visited:
          result[v]+=[node]
          visited.add(node)
          recurse(node)

  for v in sorted(as_dict):
    recurse(v)

  return dict(result)
```

Este método básicamente va visitando los nodos del grafo comenzando por el cero, en una "búsqueda en profundidad". Es decir, tan pronto como ve que uno de los hijos del nodo 0 es el 13, a continuación va a mirar los hijos del 13 (mediante recursividad). Va marcando los nodos que ya ha visitado para evitar introducirlos de nuevo en las listas de hijos.

En definitiva, te genera un diccionario similar al antes visto, pero en el que se han eliminado los "padres" en cada lista de nodos, dejando sólo los "hijos". Observa el resultado:

```
>>> tree = to_list_of_dicts_tree(G_pc)
>>> tree
{0: [13, 14],
 5: [17],
 6: [15],
 8: [11],
 10: [18],
 11: [16],
 12: [6],
 13: [3, 5, 8],
 14: [7, 9, 12],
 16: [10],
 17: [1, 4],
 18: [2]}
```

Aquí puedes ver cómo el 0 tiene de hijos al 13 y 14, y los hijos del 13 son el 3, 5 y 8 (no aparece ya el 0 porque sería su "padre"). Los nodos sin hijos (como el 3) no aparecen en este diccionario.

Si ahora quieres obtener la lista de descendientes del 13 (es decir, sus hijos, más los hijos de sus hijos, etc.) podemos escribir otra función recursiva que haga un recorrido en profundidad por este nueva representación del árbol:

```
def tree_to_list(tree, node=0):
  result = []
  def recurse(v):
    if v not in tree:
      return
    for node in tree[v]:
      result.append(node)
      recurse(node)

  for v in tree[node]:
    result.append(v)
    recurse(v)

  return result
```

A esta función le pasas el árbol (es decir, el diccionario que acabamos de generar con la otra función) y el nodo por el que quieres comenzar. Te devuelve toda la lista de descendientes de ese nodo (sin contarle a él mismo). Así, si le pasas 0 (que es el valor por defecto para ese parámetro) te devolvería la lista de todos los nodos, salvo el 0.

Probemos si funciona:

```
>>> tree_to_list(tree, 13)
[3, 5, 17, 1, 4, 8, 11, 16, 10, 18, 2]

>>> tree_to_list(tree, 5)
[17, 1, 4]

>>> tree_to_list(tree, 8)
[11, 16, 10, 18, 2]
```

Parece que produce en todos los casos el resultado que buscabas.

> **Nota**. El código anterior es para Python2 porque la etiqueta de la pregunta señalaba python2.7. Para que funcione en Python3 es necesario agregar la declaración `nonlocal result` dentro de las funciones internas llamadas `recurse` en ambos fragmentos de código.

Comment: Se agradece por la explicación me ayudo a comprender algunas dudas que tenia, estaba buscando y encontré lo siguiente: nx.dfs_successors(G_pc, 0) y su resultado es  {0: [13, 14],5: [17],6: [15], 8: [11], 10: [18], 11: [16], 12: [6], 13: [8, 3, 5], 14:[9,12, 7], 16: [10],17: [1, 4],18: [2]} que es igual a to_list_of_dicts_tree(G_pc), continué probando el código y si me arroga los resultados que estaba buscando, muchas gracias por su ayuda. Saludos